# Postgres Delete item from multiple level Jsonb

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have the following object saved in a jsonb column in Postgres db.

```
{
  "method": "method",
  "drive": [
    {
      "name": "C_Drive",
      "key": [
        {
          "is_active": true,
          "created_at": "2023-01-01T00:00:00",
          "id": 3,
          "value": "value3"
        },
        {
          "is_active": false,
          "created_at": "2022-12-01T00:00:00",
          "id": 2,
          "value": "value2"
        },
        {
          "is_active": false,
          "created_at": "2022-11-01T00:00:00",
          "id": 1,
          "value": "value1"
        }]
    },
    {
      "name": "D_Drive",
      "key": [
        {
          "is_active": true,
          "created_at": "2023-01-01T00:00:00",
          "id": 4,
          "value": "value4"
        }
    }]
}
```

I want to delete a particular key inside the drive. Say I want to delete key with "id" = 3. How do i do it?

Comment: So that's a single JSON value in one column and you want a single JSON value as the result? Can you please [edit] your question and add the expected result?

Comment: Have updated the question asking for a different output

Comment: If you know which row and the exact path you want to modify: `update your_table set jsonb_column=jsonb_column #- '{drive,0,key,0}' where id=your_row_id;` The [`#-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) removes the field under that path. [Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/kcrqndo_). Note that the json you've pasted isn't valid, so it has to be corrected before PostgreSQL lets it in.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on '{drive,0,key,0}' ? What does 0 mean here? Are they the indices of the drive and key correspondingly? I do not know the index of the item, I only know the id of the key @Zegarek

Comment: That's the path written as a `text[]` array literal. `'{drive,0,key,0}'` reads from left to right: "On the top level, open what's under `"drive"` key. Then counting from zero, fetch first element of the array - so index `0`. Then get the element under key `"key"`. That's an array where you want to target the first element, so index `0`.

Comment: If you're targetting based on the value of a key within each `"key"` array element, within each `"drive"` array element, you can do that by "opening up" the json to be interacted with in a SQL-like manner, or by constructing a custom `jsonpath`. I'll be able to post an example in two hours if there won't be any answers by then.

Comment: @Zegarek Haven't figured out a clean way of doing it yet, let me know if you can help

Answer (score 0):

Answering your initial question:

> I want to query all keys of a drive which are is_active = false and is at rank > 1 among inactive keys of the drive based on created_at desc.
>
> Eg : In above example, I only want the result to have key with id= 1. Because it is inactive and has created_at to be older than the created_at of other inactive key (key2) of the C Drive

The first half translates directly to a [`jsonpath`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-SQLJSON-PATH) expression in [`jsonb_path_query()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE), leaving only the descending `created_at` order to be dealt with using [`row_number()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-window.html#FUNCTIONS-WINDOW-TABLE) window function or an `order by` with `offset 1`, to skip the first one: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Zy8gMo97).

```sql
select k
from ( select jsonb_path_query(col1,'$.drive[*].key[*] ? (@.is_active==false)') as k
       from test_table ) as subquery
order by (k ->> 'created_at')::timestamp desc
offset 1;
```

---

Answering your new question, after the edit: you could first list possible paths using a [custom function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/310127/242866):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION jsonb_paths (data jsonb, prefix text[] default '{}') 
  RETURNS SETOF text[] STABLE PARALLEL SAFE LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $function$
DECLARE
    key     text;
    value   jsonb;
    path    text[];
    counter integer := 0;
BEGIN
    IF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'object' THEN
        FOR key, value IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_each(data)
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT array_append(prefix, key);
            IF jsonb_typeof(value) IN ('array', 'object') THEN
                RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM jsonb_paths (value, array_append(prefix, key));
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    ELSIF jsonb_typeof(data) = 'array' THEN
        FOR value IN SELECT * FROM jsonb_array_elements(data)
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT array_append(prefix, counter::text);
            IF jsonb_typeof(value) IN ('array', 'object') THEN
                RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM jsonb_paths (value, array_append(prefix, counter::text));
            END IF;
            counter := counter + 1;
        END LOOP;
    END IF;
END $function$;
```

Then select one based on your criteria and use it for [`#-` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE): [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/DkDY20h1)

```sql
with paths(id,path_arr) as 
( select id, 
         path_arr
  from (select id, col1, jsonb_paths(col1) path_arr
        from test_table) c
  where path_arr[1]='drive'
    and path_arr[3]='key'
    and array_length(path_arr,1)=4
    and (col1 #> path_arr) @@ '$.id == 3'  )
update test_table a
set col1 = a.col1 #- b.path_arr
from paths as b
where a.id=b.id;
```

It's very flexible but pretty ineffective, especially with large and complex `jsonb` values.

Comment: Unfortunately, as of v15.2 `jsonpath`-based functions don't offer modification of `jsonb`, only inspection, and there's nothing that would return static `text[]` paths based on a `'$.drive[*].key[*] ? (@.id==3)'::jsonpath` and `text[]`-based path interprets the `*` wildcard as a literal `"*"` key.